# How can I model a domain that include roles with several attributes?

Tags: datomic

I have read the documentation, and I am struggling with the following case (probably I am thinking in neo4j and hyperedges and that's why I can think clearly here):

Assume that I want to model the following entities: `:person` (with some attributes like `:name`, `id`, etc), `:school` (again some attributes) the relation ship of between the `school` and the `person` could be like `:student` or `:teacher`. And this could evolve through time (a :person could not be related to the school, later is a `:student` and much later maybe as a `:teacher`)

When the `:person` is a `:student` it will have an student-id, and as a `:teacher` it will have another id lets say teacher-id.

So, should I have:

```
:person/name 'John'
:school/id 'SCHOOL-1'
:student/name 'John'
:student/school 'SCHOOL-1'
```

? How I should include information as the `student-id`, What if there is more schools?

But now, it seems to me that the relationship between this entities is an hyperedge (that's why I mentioned neo4j). And I don't know what is the best way of modelling this is datomic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have a good example of using Datomic to keep track of James Bond and various villians [available here](https://github.com/io-tupelo-demo/datomic).  Everything is written in the form of unit tests using the [Tupelo Datomic library](https://github.com/io-tupelo/datomic) so it is easy to verify the base project and any changes you have:

```
~/io.tupelo.demo/datomic > lct
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

lein test _bootstrap

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

lein test tst.tupelo.datomic.bond

Ran 2 tests containing 35 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

The above will work with Datomic Free edition, so you don't even need a paid license to get started.

---

In the Bond example, the characters may have multiple weapons, which are modeled as a set:

```
; Create some antagonists and load them into the db.  We can specify some of the
; attribute-value pairs at the time of creation, and add others later. Note that
; whenever we are adding multiple values for an attribute in a single step (e.g.
; :weapon/type), we must wrap all of the values in a set. Note that the set
; implies there can never be duplicate weapons for any one person.  As before,
; we immediately commit the new entities into the DB.
(td/transact *conn*
  (td/new-entity { :person/name "James Bond" :location "London"     :weapon/type #{ :weapon/gun :weapon/wit   } } )
  (td/new-entity { :person/name "M"          :location "London"     :weapon/type #{ :weapon/gun :weapon/guile } } )
  (td/new-entity { :person/name "Dr No"      :location "Caribbean"  :weapon/type    :weapon/gun                 } ))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this doesn't solve my problem (I think so, but I could be confused). For example, A Person is an student, students has many more attributes like School, student_id, etc. It seems to me that the answer is to have a entity registry (that includes a person, a school and an id) but it seems awkward that I shifted from having entities (like person and student) to have persons and registries... Does this makes sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I see no need for a registry of any sort.